# почему не заливается на сервер из за удаленного пакета ошибка с composer.lock ? laravel

Tags: laravel, git

установил `carbon` в `laravel 8` а оказалось что там он уже по умолчанию

1. удалил из `composer.json` строку `"nesbot/carbon": "^2.48"`,
2. сделал `composer update`
3. залил на гитлаб
4. теперь не хочет заливаться на сервер пишет:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
> composer.lock
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

Comment: значит на сервере вручную меняли что-то.. push с флагом --force сделайте, он перезапишет изменения на сервере файлами с гита

Comment: в этом файле  composer.lock не менял

Comment: выполните команду `git status` и увидите что за файлы менялись

Comment: я их не менял , но выполнил команду и отменил правку тогда залилось

Comment: @junior когда вы пытаетесь "запушить" изменения в Git - git видит что есть разница между вашей локальной копией ветки и удаленной (remote) - он пытается перед тем как запушить, синхронизировать ветки с помощью merge.  Из-за того что файл composer.lock был изменен на Git-е и сейчас вы пытаетесь тоже измененный файл залить в Git - отсюда и ошибка которая вам говорит "файл composer.lock будет перезаписан после merge". Git предлагает вам их "закомитить" либо же "застешить". Советую все же закомитить если уверены в своих изменениях.